# connected manifolds with infinite or n charts

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

does anybody know that there exists a manifold which has an infinite chart for cover it or not? My teacher and I could not find.

I have tried it but all the manifolds I know are covering with two or 3 charts.

Edit: I thought sphere with n-dimensional which cut with a KNOT and torus should have more than 3 charts.

Comment: Do you seek a *single* manifold only  covered by infinitely many charts?

Comment: hi, yes exactly. but i want that the charts not repeated and the manifold be connected . @coffeemath

Comment: Another question-- Would it be enough to give, for each specific $n>3,$ a manifold requiring $n$ (distinct) charts at least? [With manifold connected, naturally]

Comment: u know exactly i want a manifold that requiring n charts at list or infinite at least,some complicated manifold charts.and its better to be a 2 dimensional manifold @coffeemath

Comment: Your question is really that: Is there a manifold that cannot be covered by finitely many chart?

Comment: yes exactly.and the manifold be connected.i want to know if it doesnt covered infinitely, so someone give me an example of a connected manifold which covered by several manifold(10 or 100 or 1000 charts for example)   @JohnMa

Answer (score 2):

Quotes from Mathoverflow ([Least number of charts to describe a given manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2615/least-number-of-charts-to-describe-a-given-manifold)):

The question:

> I'm wondering if there is a standard reference discussing the least number of charts in an atlas of a given manifold required to describe it.

One answer:

> I have found on the second page of Michor "Topics in Differential Geometry": "Note finally that any manifold $M$ admits a finite atlas consisting of $\dim M + 1$ not connected charts. This is a consequence of topological dimension theory [cf. Nagata, Modern Dimension Theory]; a proof for manifolds may be found in [cf. Greub, Halperin, Vanstone, Connections, curvature and cohomology. I]."

The *charts* can be disconnected. Is this OK?

Comment: One can connect the charts using "little tubes"

Comment: There is another MO question on the same subject, which has some other information, by the way; I can't find it now, sadly.

Comment: your answer is useful but i did not mean connecting of charts are important.it is clearly not important that charts are disconnect.*i want a shape or figure of a manifold which be connected and have infinite charts or many charts*. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: I don't know what that comment means, sorry.

Comment: u gave my answer about the number of charts. from your answer i understood that every manifold has finite charts.but also i want an example of a connected manifold which has for example 10 charts.i didnt find a figure which satisfies  10 charts on the internet(with google search). @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez